# jQuery -use hide/show to toggle content so that some displays when javascript is enabled and other content when its *disabled*?

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I'm trying to use jQuery to hide content with class no_js, and show content with class js. I use this for buttons on a form; when Javascript is enabled, I show the type="button" that binds `onclick` to a Javascript function, and when Javascript is disabled, the page shows (shown by default) the `type="submit"` button. Here's what I have so far:

```
<input class="no_js" type="Submit" value="Generate"/>
<input class="js" type="button" value="Generate_JS" onclick="generate_password()"/>
```

.js elements are set to `display:none` in the style sheet. I wanted to use hide/show or toggle, because the elements may have different display types (`inline`, `inline-block`, it depends on the element) so I can't just set the CSS properties using display (and this script is site wide, so it's based on class, not ID).

Can someone please help me? Right now, the Generate button shows all the time, and the Generate_JS button *never* shows.

EDIT: Sorry, I guess I can't put code in my comments? This is the code I'm using in my header, and the results are still the same.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    $(".no_js").hide();
    $(".js").show();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by an unrelated error in my web host's system; they were experiencing packet loss on the majority of packets that went through, and in all that mess, the JQuery library that I uploaded hadn't made it through. My original code is working again.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="no_js" type="Submit" value="Generate" />  
<input class="js" type="button" value="Generate_JS" onclick="generate_password()" style="display: none"/>
<script>
$("input.js").show();
$("input.no_js").hide();
<script>
```

Comment: I tested your exact code, and it doesn't work. Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: The Generate button shows all the time (whether or not javascript is enabled or disabled) and the Generate_js button never shows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `<noscript>` element, which will only display when no scripting language is detected, in all of the current browsers that would be javascript.

Comment: I know about the noscript element, but that doesn't help me to display different content when it's enabled. Also, the noscript element can cause problems for XHTML 1.0 Strict, which I'm using exclusively.